# How do I get one singel array inside a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, function, animation, for-loop, canvas

i have a simpel game but when the red ball hits the blue ball while in motion the SPLICING desen't work i get the error form the movement script. I think the best solution to this problem is to registrer a collition when only the red ball hits the blu ball. can somone help me whith that?

To se a demo clik the link[DEMO](http://elevweb.akershus-fk.no/~stmo0403/it2/spill/) press R to restart

Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var tileldig = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);
var tekst = document.getElementById("tekst")
var log = document.getElementById("log")
var highlog = document.getElementById("highlog")

var kuler = [{
  r: 10,
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height - 100,
  f: "red",
  dy: 0
}, ];

var fiender = [{
  r: 20,
  x: tileldig,
  y: -20,
  vx: 0,
  vy: 1,
}, ];

//var snd = new Audio("Skudd.m4a");

var poeng = 0;
var highscore = 0;
var høyre = 0;
var venstre = 0;
var opp = 0;
var ned = 0;
var restart = 0;
var død = 0;


document.onkeydown = function tast(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) { // høyre
    høyre = 1;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) { // venstre
    venstre = 1;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) { // opp 
    opp = 1;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) { // ned
    ned = 1;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    newskudd();
    // snd.play();
    console.log("hit space")
  }

  if (e.keyCode == 82) {
    init();
    log.innerHTML += ("Poeng: " + poeng)
    poeng = 0;
  }
}
document.onkeyup = function tast2(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) { // høyre
    høyre = 0;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) { // venstre
    venstre = 0;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) { // opp 
    opp = 0;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) { // ned
    ned = 0;
  }
}

function spill() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < kuler.length; i++) {
    kuler[i].x += 0;
    kuler[i].y += kuler[i].dy;


    ctx.fillStyle = kuler[i].f;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(kuler[i].x, kuler[i].y, kuler[i].r, 2 * Math.PI, 0);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    if (kuler[0].x >= canvas.width - kuler[0].r) {
      kuler[0].x = canvas.width - kuler[0].r
    };
    if (kuler[0].x <= 0 + kuler[0].r) {
      kuler[0].x = 0 + kuler[0].r
    };
    if (kuler[0].y >= canvas.height - kuler[0].r) {
      kuler[0].y = canvas.height - kuler[0].r
    };
    if (kuler[0].y <= 0 + kuler[0].r) {
      kuler[0].y = 0 + kuler[0].r
    };

    for (var j = 0; j < fiender.length; j++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(fiender[j].x, fiender[j].y, fiender[j].r, 2 * Math.PI, 0);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();


      if (fiender[j].x >= canvas.width - fiender[j].r) {
        fiender[j].x = canvas.width - fiender[j].r;
      };
      if (fiender[j].x <= 0 + fiender[j].r) {
        fiender[j].x = 0 + fiender[j].r;
      };
      if (fiender[j].vy >= 2) {
        fiender[j].vy = 2;
      };

      var distanceFromCenters = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(fiender[j].x - kuler[i].x), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(fiender[j].y - kuler[i].y), 2)); // you have a collision
      if (distanceFromCenters <= (fiender[j].r + kuler[i].r)) {
        fiender.splice(j, 1);
        kuler.splice(i, 1);
        poeng += 1;
        restart = 1;        
      } else if (fiender[j].y > canvas.height) {
        fiender.splice(j, 1)
      } 

      if (j > 1) {
        fiender.splice(j, 1)
      }

      log.innerHTML = ("<br>" + "Score denne runden: " + poeng + "</br>" + "<br>" + "Highscore: " + highscore + "</br>")
      if (poeng >= highscore) {
        log.innerHTML += ("<br>" + "Ny Highscore: " + highscore + "</br>")
        highscore = poeng;
      }
    }
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < fiender.length; j++) {
    fiender[j].y += fiender[j].vy;
  }

  if (venstre == 1) {
    kuler[0].x -= 4;
  }
  if (høyre == 1) {
    kuler[0].x += 4;;
  }
  if (opp == 1) {
    kuler[0].y -= 4;
  }
  if (ned == 1) {
    kuler[0].y += 4;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(spill);
  return;
}


document.onload = spill();

function newskudd() {
  var nyttskudd = {
    x: kuler[0].x,
    y: kuler[0].y,
    r: 5,
    dy: -5,
    f: "white"
  };
  kuler.push(nyttskudd);
};

setInterval(function() {
  fiender.push({
    r: 20,
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1),
    y: -20,
    vx: 0,
    vy: 1,
    f: "green"
  });
}, 1000);

function init() {
  kuler = [{
    r: 10,
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height - 100,
    f: "red",
    dy: 0
  }, ];

  fiender = [{
    r: 20,
    x: tileldig,
    y: -20,
    vx: 0,
    vy: 1,
  }, ];
}
```

Comment: This is way too much code for anyone to look at. Please reduce it to 20%, or ideally 10%. The good news: as you're doing that, you'll probably find the problem yourself!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: On IE11 I'm not getting an error in the debugger--all the balls just disappear when red collides with blue.  Please clarify your question.